# __uint128_t on mingw gcc

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, 128-bit, int128

I'm trying to compile a c program under mingw gcc. This program is using an `__uint128_t` integer. When I try to compile it under the standard ubuntu gcc on the same 64-bit machine, it perfectly works. But then, when I try to compile it for windows under mingw, it simply doesn't even recognize the `__uint128_t` keyword. What does this mean? There aren't 128 bit integers under mingw?
If not, is there any programming language for windows which has native (and FAST) 128 bit integers?

Answer (score 7):

You need

- a relatively recent version of gcc
- a version compiled with native 64 bit integer support

`__int128_t` is then emulated by using pairs of `int64_t` in the same way as 64bit integers are emulated with 32bit if they are not available on 32bit compiles

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get the same problem using Code::Blocks and the default mingw install (which is IA32 btw), however, when I installed [TDM-MinGW64](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/), it compiled fine (after adding the x64 compiler to C::B). So make sure your mingw build is targeting x64 (with `-m64`) *and* it is an x64 build of mingw, as `__uint128_t` is an optional x64 ABI extension.

whatever windows IDE you are using won't pick up `__int128_t` as a keyword though, as its a special GCC extension (as mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

> But then, when I try to compile it for windows under mingw, it simply doesn't even recognize the __uint128_t keyword. What does this mean? There aren't 128 bit integers under mingw?

Perform `gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep INT128`. If it output the macro `#define __SIZEOF_INT128__ 16`, then `__uint128_t` is available. If it does not output the macro or its less than 16, then `__uint128_t` is not available.

Also see [128-bit integer - nonsensical documentation?](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2015-08/msg00185.html) on the GCC users mailing list.