# identifier "__int128_t" is undefined

Tags: c++, g++, mingw, visual-studio-code, identifier

I am trying to use a 128 data type "__int128_t" in my VSCode while writing a C++ program, but I am getting an error saying **identifier "__int128_t" is undefined**. However, it works perfectly on my friend's PC. I thought since he installed the MinGW GCC compiler recently so there must be an issue with my version as it is comparatively old as compared to his, so I updated my g++ to version 11.2.0. Still, even after this, "__int128_t" is not working in my C++ program which I am writing in VS Code. This is my code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void fastIO()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
}
int main()
{
    fastIO();
    long long input[100000], n;
    cin >> n;
    __int128_t sum1 = (n * (n + 1)) / 2;
    __int128_t sum2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        cin >> input[i];
        sum2 += input[i];
    }
    cout << sum1 - sum2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7174419/580083.

Comment: Also note that the closed form sum expression `(n * (n + 1)) / 2` will be evaluated in `long long` arithmetic. Promote one of the coefficients to __int128_t using a `static_cast`.

Comment: Why do you have to use a 128 bit integer? What are the input constraints?

Comment: In gcc-11.2 I am getting different errors about operator << ()

Comment: Make sure you compile in 64 bit mode